# Multiple SQL Servers in containers in Kubernetes cluster and appropriate configuration

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, kubernetes, yaml

I'm fairly new to the whole concept of the microservice architecture, but I have managed to create a simple proof of concept application, which consists of 1 Blazor server-side front-end, 6 microservices, which are all .NET 6 WEB APIs and were previously using an InMemory database and they all seeded mock data inside of their DBs on startup. Now I'm trying to make each of them use their own SQL Server 2019 database (inside of containers of course) instead of the InMemory database. I am very sorry for the very long and detailed description, but please kindly read through.

So, to visualise it a bit:

- Kubernetes cluster (orchestrates the below containers)

  - Blazor app (runs within a container) -> talks to the 6 WebAPIs below
  - WebAPI1 (runs within a container) -> talks to it's SQL Server 2019 DB inside of a container
  - WebAPI2 (runs within a container) -> talks to it's SQL Server 2019 DB inside of a container
  - WebAPI3 (runs within a container) -> talks to it's SQL Server 2019 DB inside of a container
  - WebAPI4 (runs within a container) -> talks to it's SQL Server 2019 DB inside of a container
  - WebAPI5 (runs within a container) -> talks to it's SQL Server 2019 DB inside of a container
  - WebAPI6 (runs within a container) -> talks to it's SQL Server 2019 DB inside of a container

I've started by creating PersistentVolueClaims for each of the SQL Servers like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-<name of the web api>-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
```

and I've written one of these for each of the WebAPIs and used `kubectl apply -f <name>.yaml` for each of them, resulting in:

```
PS E:\OceniFilm> kubectl get pvc
NAME                       STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mssql-identiteta-claim     Bound    pvc-9f2a3ff7-f0b2-4ae8-990c-9de1766d056f   500Mi      RWX            hostpath       3s
mssql-igralci-claim        Bound    pvc-d9cb4791-12a2-4225-9f22-4e4c5aa7b022   500Mi      RWX            hostpath       8s
mssql-komentiranje-claim   Bound    pvc-067469fe-5166-4a36-a5e9-b216136a9dca   500Mi      RWX            hostpath       14s
mssql-ocenjevanje-claim    Bound    pvc-a8231a42-2d93-4b41-b214-2ba9c32d8518   500Mi      RWX            hostpath       18s
mssql-seznami-claim        Bound    pvc-5b1d64b8-cc60-4f57-a700-3470ded1c5c9   500Mi      RWX            hostpath       23s
mssql-videoteka-claim      Bound    pvc-197bbafc-57e9-4153-b176-70f2a7a80965   500Mi      RWX            hostpath       24m
```

Then I wrote the deployment files for each of the SQL Servers, this is one of them:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-<name of the web api>-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mssql
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
          - name: MSSQL_PID
            value: "Express"
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "Y"
          - name: SA_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mssql
                key: SA_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
            name: mssqldb
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-<name of the web api pvc claim>-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-clusterip-<name of the web api>-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
  - name: mssql
    protocol: TCP
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-<name of the web api>-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 56780
    targetPort: 1433
```

And of course, applied all of these 6 using `kubectl apply -f <name-depl>.yaml`, that creates a pod and inside of it a container with my web api. All good all fine.

And for the web api deployment files, here is one of them:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <name of the web api>-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <name of the web api>service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <name of the web api>service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: <name of the web api>service
          image: myName/<name of the web api>:latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <name of the web api>-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: <name of the web api>service
  ports:
  - name: <name of the web api>service
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

In the `appsettings.json` of each Web API I have set:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "<name of Web API>SQLServ": "Server=mssql-clusterip-<name of Web API>-srv,1433;Initial Catalog=<name of Web API>DB;User ID=sa;Password=M!cr0s3rv!ce;"
  }
```

And in the program.cs of each Web API I use this connection string to connect, it then calls a Seeding function, to execute a migration

[image: program.cs]

[image: preparedb.cs]

So, the way I go about testing this:

1. I `kubectl apply` the pvc-webapi.yaml file (if it's not there yet)
2. I `kubectl apply` the mssql-webapi-depl.yaml file
3. I `kubectl apply` the webapi-depl.yaml file (to generate the database migration - this is only initially)

In SSMS I connect to the SQL Server and I can see that the migration has been applied and database created:

[image: dbcreated]

And if I then look at services:

```
PS E:\OceniFilm> kubectl get svc
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
kubernetes                      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP           2m45s
mssql-clusterip-videoteka-srv   ClusterIP      10.98.103.67     <none>        1433/TCP          32s
mssql-videoteka-loadbalancer    LoadBalancer   10.107.101.145   localhost     56785:32536/TCP   32s
videoteka-clusterip-srv         ClusterIP      10.109.115.15    <none>        80/TCP            14s
```

Then I repeat the process to do this for the other sql servers:

1. I `kubectl apply` the pvc-webapi2.yaml file (if it's not there yet)
2. I `kubectl apply` the mssql-webapi2-depl.yaml file
3. I `kubectl apply` the webapi2-depl.yaml file (to generate the database migration - this is only initially)

And it does the migration and generates the DB and everything (looking at the container logs), but when I connect to the sql server to check if it's there, it's not?

Then I connect back to the first sql server, from the first generating of the database and lo and behold, both databases are on this server:

[image]

So basically this is my issues, they are both generated on this one sql server instead of each database generating in it's own sql server. I have no idea what's going on there. I'm guessing something with configuration, perhaps the persistentvolumeclaims overwriting or using wrong ones?

What is the correct way of dealing with multiple sql servers in a Kubernetes cluster?

If you read through this entire thing, I kindly thank you and if you think you know what is going wrong here, please help me.

Comment: Why do you want multiple SQL Servers instead of each microservice having a database on a shared SQL Server?  That would be much simpler and perform much better.

Comment: That is a fact, but I would still like to know what is going on here.

Comment: Could you debug your **ConnectionStrings** in your program.cs after the first connection to review what value is stored? This is so that you can review this change in the next **Web API** .

Answer (score 0):

You should probably know that a PVC is only a claim for a PV that is the actual representation of your backend storage in kubernetes, have they been generated? Do you have a storageClass ? Which type of kubernetes cluster are you using? Add the output of `kubectl get pv` command...  Give us also the status of the pods including the MySQL one (kubectl get pods)... The databases in kubernetes should not be deployed under a k8s "deployment" object but a "statefulset" object. The best practice would be to deploy only one statefulset and create all databases in the only MySQL SGBD deployed with this statefulset.

So here I think your databases are not correctly running.